its SharePoint issue failing to file upload
const endpoint = ${environment.sharepointUpload}GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('${environment.sharepointDir}/${projectId}/documents/${folderName}')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='${fileName}');
this above url working in UAT but failing in production angular issue when file upload
through 404 not found

The 404 error suggests that the URL is incorrect or the file is not found in the specified location. Please double-check the URL and ensure that the file exists in the specified location.
Reference：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-large-files-by-using-rest

thanks for answer ..actually file was not uploaded because of filename we are passing instead of Filename so there was  issue for file upload so not able to find out the file in location so it is throwing 404 .
